# Error: Nock: No match for request

Tags: node.js, nock

I am receiving following error

```
{ error: 
   { Error: Nock: No match for request {
     "method": "GET",
     "url": "http://localhost:3000/admin/orders/30075889/transactions.json",
     "headers": {
       "content-type": "application/json",
       "host": "localhost:3000"
     }
   } Got instead {
     "method": "GET",
     "url": "http://localhost:3000/admin/orders/30075889/transactions.json",
     "headers": {
       "content-type": "application/json",
       "host": "localhost:3000"
     }
   }
```

The url is as expected, not sure what's wrong, any pointer?

Comment: I am calling 2 apis, 1 is post and 1 is get. And doing Promise.all([1stApi, 2edApi]). But getting error as - Error: Nock: No match for request. When I put any 1 of the both in Promise.all(), then works fine. Any suggestion why this happens for 2 api calls?

Answer (score 32):

Use `.log(console.log)` to see the exact error message.

EX :

```
nock('https://test.org/sample')
.persist()
.log(console.log)
.get('/test')
.query({})
.reply(200, response);
```

When you use this and run the test, you will see something like this in the console

```
matching https://test.org/sample/test to GET https://test.org/sample/test with query({}): **true/false**.
```

If it says true, your request should be good. But if it says false, check both the requests and make sure they match.

Comment: Is it deprecated? `TypeError: nock(...).log is not a function`

Comment: Use the env variable `DEBUG=nock.*` instead of `.log(...)`, log is no longer supported. i.e.: `DEBUG=nock.* jest -i your/test/file.test.js`

Answer (score 30):

Nock interceptors don't persist by default. For every request nock needs an interceptor. It looks like you only setup interceptor once and expect it to work for every request. If you want your interceptors to persist use `.persist()` option something like below.

```
var scope = nock('http://localhost.com')
  .persist()
  .get(/.*/)
  .reply(200, 'Nock all get requests!');
```

Comment: I hace persist() but the error is still coming....it just started coming up

Answer (score 11):

you can display at any time prepared nocks, it's almost always a typo... ;)

`console.log(nock.activeMocks());`

(debuger in webstorm sucks and nock is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

sometimes can be a `encodedQueryParams: true` option the problem

encoding query params is default behaviour these days, works well without such an option

Answer (score 0):

Mostly a typo. In my case I had to add a `/` before the string in get method.
`.get('/list')`