# React API test with Nock failing with "Error : Nock : No match for request"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nock

Here's the Express Route code that is working fine in back and frontend.

// Edit/update by vessel_type by_id - Working

```
router.put("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  Vessel_Type.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    req.body,

    { new: true },
    (err, updatedRecord) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return next(err);
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(updatedRecord);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

And here's my API test code in React front-end with [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock)

```
  it("API test-3 - PUT (/api/vesseltype/id)", done => {
    nock(host)
      .defaultReplyHeaders({
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      })
      .persist()
      .log(console.log)
      .put("/api/vesseltype/5c62cc8f1774b626cd7fdbe6", {
        vesseltype: "Super Large Cargo Ship-45"
      })
      .delayBody(1000)
      .reply(200, "PUT/EDIT data with reqheaders");

    axios
      .put("http://localhost:3000/api/vesseltype/5c62cc8f1774b626cd7fdbe6", {
        vesseltype: "Super Large Cargo Ship-45"
      })
      .then(response => {
        expect(response.data).toBe("PUT/EDIT data with reqheaders");
        expect(typeof response.data).toBe("string");
        done();
      });
  });
```

The console logging of the error from the test gives the following in Terminal

```
    console.log node_modules/nock/lib/interceptor.js:332
    matching http://localhost:3000/api/vesseltype/5c62cc8f1774b626cd7fdbe6 to PUT http://localhost:3000/api/vesseltype/5c62cc8f1774b626cd7fdbe6: false

  console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
    Error: Error: Nock: No match for request {
      "method": "OPTIONS",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/vesseltype/5c62cc8f1774b626cd7fdbe6",
      "headers": {
        "origin": "http://localhost",
        "access-control-request-method": "PUT",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (linux) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) jsdom/11.12.0",
        "host": "localhost:3000",
        "content-length": 0
      }
    }
        at Object.dispatchError (/home/paul/codes-Lap/React/Volteo/IES/IES-Rohan-WIP/client/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:65:19)
        at EventEmitter.client.on.err (/home/paul/codes-Lap/React/Volteo/IES/IES-Rohan-WIP/client/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:676:20)
        at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:202:15)
```

**However my PUT routes (http://localhost:3000/api/vesseltype/5c62cc8f1774b626cd7fdbe6) is matching perfectly between nock and axios.**

I have gone through these github issues and SO questions [here](https://github.com/nock/nock/issues/543), [here](https://github.com/nock/nock/issues/1049), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674675/error-nock-no-match-for-request) but those solutions did not help me.

Comment: Even [this github issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/305#issuecomment-272162405)?

Comment: Also, if you’re not married to nock, [msw](https://mswjs.io/) is my new go to library for http requests during development and testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jest + react, your jest config sets the `testEnviromnent` to `jsdom`.  But nock requires a `node` environment to mock axios.

One workaround is to set the [jest testEnvironment](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string) in the nock test
file only, so that it doesn't interfere with your react tests.  You can do this by adding this docblock at the top of your jest files where you're testing your network calls:

```
/** @jest-environment node */
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your framework/lib calls OPTIONS request before calling the PUT.
It's related with CORS.
[Described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it)

You may try nock-ing OPTIONS.

Comment: Looks like the request isn’t being nock’ed at all and it’s calling a real server instead